# Survival analysis: probability of dying between two given times

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

If the probability of surviving $1$ month is $0.5$ and the probability of surviving $2$ months is $0.3$, I understand that the conditional probability of surviving $2$ months *given* having survived one month is $0.3 / 0.5 = 0.6$.

However, I'm trying to calculate the probability at the outset of dying between $1$ and $2$ months. This must mean the probability of **both** surviving $1$ month **and** surviving less than $2$ months given having survived $1$ month. How do I set up the math for this? If they were independent events, we could multiply: $0.5 \times 0.3 = 0.15$. But they're not independent, are they?

Comment: They are not independent.  The probabilities are fairly clearly: (a) surviving one month  $0.5$; (b) surviving one month and surviving two months $0.3$; (c) surviving one month but not surviving two months $0.5-0.3=0.2$; (d) not surviving two months given you did survive one month $\frac{0.2}{0.5}=1-0.6=0.4$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A_i$ be the event of surviving at the end of month $i$.
So $A_1$ is the event of surviving at the end of first month.
Similarly $A_2$.

Then $A_1,A_2$ are dependent because$$P(A_1\wedge A_2)=P(\text{surviving at the end of first and second month})=P(A_2)\\\ne P(A_1)\times P(A_2)$$

In fact $A_2$ can happen only if $A_1$ does.

You want to find $P(\text{surviving at the end of first month and not surviving at the end of second month})=P(A_1\wedge A_2^C).$

First remember for any two events $P,Q,P(P|Q)+P(P^C|Q)=1$. So$$\begin{align*}&P(A_2^C|A_1)=1-\underbrace{P(A_2|A_1)}_\color{red}{\text{found by you as }0.6}=0.4\\\implies&P(A_2^C\wedge A_1)=0.4P(A_1)=0.4\times0.5=0.2.\end{align*}$$

Comment: Okay, I'll elaborate.

Comment: See the edit @JeremyB

Comment: Glad to be of help!

Comment: I have one follow-up question: Given that a subject has already survived to time A1, I would like to find the probability of dying between A2 and A3. Do I first find P(A2) and P(A3) conditional on P(A1) - i.e. P(A2)/P(A1) and P(A3)/P(A1) - and then proceed as above?

Comment: To find $P(A_2\text{ and } A_3^C|A_1)=\frac{P(A_2\text{ and }A_3^C\text{ and }A_1)}{P(A_1)}=\frac{P(A_2\text{ and }A_3^C)}{P(A_1)}$, you need to find the numerator. $P(A_2\text{ and }A_3^C)$ in a manner similar to the above. @JeremyB

Comment: Perfect, thanks again!